# Connect PHP to Oracle database oci pdo Fedora 25 server - Error: could not find driver

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oci8, fedora-25

I can't seem to connect to an Oracle db from my webserver.

I have installed the Oracle 12.1 instantclient and sdk packages as per the Oracle instructions.

I have installed pear and pecl to install oci8 as required.

When I visit my webpage that performs a basic connect and SELECT from db, it simply displays: Error: could not find driver. Here is my webpage php code:

```
<?php
  try {
    $dbb = new PDO("oci:dbname=DBSERVER", "DBASE", "password");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
  $sql = "select NAME from BUILDER.MY_SCHEMAS"; ?> <html> <head>
    <title>Results Test Page</title> </head> <body> <table width ="500" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Result Set</th>
      <tr> <?php
  foreach ($dbb->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['NAME']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
?> </table> </body> </html>
```

My php.ini file, I added:

```
extension=oci8.so
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so"
extension=pdo.so
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so"
```

I am not sure where to go from here and I'm scratching my head as I've had this working before. Do I need to install other packages or php extensions? Or maybe there are Oracle client settings I need to change.

I've been trying to get this to work for hours now and I am tempted to throw the machine out of the nearest window at the moment!!

Or - is there a better/easier way of connecting php with an Oracle database?

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Comment: You should only have one instance of `extension_dir` and it should specify (per [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir)): "In what **directory** PHP should look for dynamically loadable extensions.". The extensions are then loaded relative to that.

Comment: You're also loading the vanilla `OCI` driver, not `PDO_OCI`.

Comment: I realise I do not have the oci8.so, or pdo_oci.so files in my php modules folder. Trying to pecl install oci8 gives me errors. Is there a way around this that you know of?

Comment: The mix of PDO & OCI8 isn't helping.  Choose one.  The OCI8 driver is preferred, if only because it is easier to add to an existing PHP environment.  You don't say which 'Oracle instructions' you followed, but a common problem is not having LD_LIBRARY_PATH set where Apache can find it.  Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html